# Alias to start a shell script executes automatically

Tags: bash, shell, alias, zsh

I am trying to create an alias to start a shell script as below:

> alias emulate="~/start_emulator.zsh"

But as soon as i save and source the zshrc file, the script executes automatically instead of typing the alias.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Please remove everything except this line from your zshrc and try again in a new terminal. I'm guessing the problem will go away. You can then find which line in your original zshrc calls it (`emulate` is the zsh built-in for setting the shell compatibility mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your script in `/usr/bin/`.
You shouldn't even need an alias at all then.